# Ansible extract sub-string from a matched element of a List variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-filter

I have a variable, which is a **list** as below:

```
"test_list": [
     "some text here",
     "server1",
     "command1 parameter1",
     "path/to/command2 parameter2 server1_202012",
     "some more text",
     "New backup file is server1_202019"
    ]
```

I am trying to extract the substring `server1_202019` which is at the end of the line that starts with `New backup file...`. There is only one line like this and I've tried below option to get the substring.

```
- set_fact: 
    test_name: "{{ test_list | select('^New backup file is (.+)$','\\1') }}"
```

and the output I've received is:

```
"test_name": "<generator object _select_or_reject at 0x3fe5b40>"
```

I've tried below code also, but failed.

```
- set_fact: 
    test_name: "{{ test_list | regex_search('^New backup file is (.+)$','\\1') }}"
```

The error is:

```
"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ test_list | regex_search('^New backup file is (.+)$','\\\\1') }}): ..... expected string or buffer"
```

Could somebody please suggest how I can get the output as below:

```
"test_name": "server1_202019"
```

The ansible version I'm using is 2.9

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the item from the list and then use `regex_replace`. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        test_name: "{{ test_list|
                       select('regex', my_regex)|
                       first|
                       regex_replace(my_regex, my_replace) }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^New backup file is (.*)$'
        my_replace: '\1'
    - debug:
        var: test_name
```

give

```
"test_name": "server1_202019"
```

Comment: Thanks so much Botka, it worked perfectly. I've also learned that the 'first' is in place to sort out the 'generator object _select_or_reject at 0x3fe5b40' issue.

Comment: Right, it depends on what you want. Use filter `list`  to get the full list, if needed. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since `test_list` is a list, you need to loop through the items to be matched using regex. Something like below can be done.

```
- set_fact:
    matched: "{{ item | regex_search('^New backup file is (.+)$','\\1') }}"
  loop: "{{ test_list }}"
  register: matching_items

- debug:
    var: item.ansible_facts.matched
  with_items: "{{ matching_items.results }}"
  when: item.ansible_facts.matched != ""
```

Should output like below for debug:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'matched': ''}, 'failed': False, 'item': 'some text here', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'matched': ''}, 'failed': False, 'item': 'server1', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'matched': ''}, 'failed': False, 'item': 'command1 parameter1', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'matched': ''}, 'failed': False, 'item': 'path/to/command2 parameter2 server1_202012', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'matched': ['server1_202019']}, 'failed': False, 'item': 'New backup file is server1_202019', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "matched": [
                "server1_202019"
            ]
        },
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "item": "New backup file is server1_202019"
    },
    "item.ansible_facts.matched": [
        "server1_202019"
    ]
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'matched': ''}, 'failed': False, 'item': 'some more text', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'})
```

Comment: This works only because the line is the last one. Otherwise, the result is an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. Have updated the code and good learning from your post.

Comment: Thank you Mamun, I have tried the code before the edit and the output turned out to be empty.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, updated the code as @VladimirBotka pointed out. Learnt something new from your question too.